# Send a notification after uploading multiple files with Dropzone JS

Tags: php, dropzone.js

I have been working on a project where user uploads image on other users profile page. I have been successful in uploading and sending emails also but it sends multiple emails if there are multiple files in a single upload.

```
$sendmail = true;

if(!empty($_FILES)){

$team_id = $_GET['param1'];
$user_id = $_GET['param2'];
$id = $_GET['param3'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM team where team_id = '$team_id'" ;
$sql_result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)){
    $abcd = $row; 
} 

$targetDir = "../user_images/";
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileNamex = substr($fileName, -3);
$fileName = rand(1000,100000).md5($fileName).'_'.$fileName;
$targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;

if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] , $targetFile ) ){
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO gallery (team_id , user_id , id , userPic, token) VALUES('$team_id','$user_id','$id','$fileName','0')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    if($sendmail === true){
        $htmlContent = file_get_contents ("../email_template_header.php"); 
        $registerURL = $siteURL.'/register/';
        if($abcd['claimed'] == '1'){
            $htmlContent .= "New image(s) has been uploaded to your business. Please <a href='$registerURL'>login</a> and approve them";
        }
        else{
            $htmlContent .= "New image(s) has been uploaded to your business. Please <a href='$registerURL'>register</a> to claim your business";
        }
        $htmlContent .= file_get_contents ("../email_template_footer.php"); 

        $to = $abcd['b_email'];

        require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'localhost';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->setFrom('mail@abc.com', 'ABC');
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'New Image Uploaded';
        $mail->Body = $htmlContent;
        $mail->send();
        $mail->clearAddresses();

        $sendmail = false;
    }
}  
}
```

This doesn't work as the complete code is running for every file, there is also no loop in the default examples on http://www.dropzonejs.com/ so that I could've checked with help of a index flag whether a file has been uploaded or not. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dropzone.options.filedrop = {
  init: function () {
    this.on("complete", function (file) {
      if (this.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && this.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
        doSomething();
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: doSomething() can be a php function? or do I have to make an ajax call to my function

Comment: You need to replace it by your email send function, so you need to call send command here.

Comment: if i replace doSomething() with console.log('success') nothing is shown in console...do I have to remove php code for file upload?

Comment: Test it alone first then you can combine it with whatever you want, it's better for you to test any complicated code alone before using it.

Comment: ok thanks, its outputting in console now...forgot to change 'filedrop' ID.